Can we use “can” to make suggestions?
Can we use can to mean suggestions for third persons?

A: Jack says he doesn’t have any flour left.
B: If they reopen the grocery store around the corner, he can buy some there next week.

Does B’s response sounds like a suggestion with can?

I feel like this question can be answered using dictionary…

@user1176409 [using a dictionary]

You mean: Does B sound like an proper use of "can"?

The sense of suggestion doesn't really come just from the word "can," but from the context of the conversation.

Definitely yes, “can” can mean suggestion (not only for third-persons), see here.

“can” is used to make a suggestion or offer.
Ex: "We can have another drink if you like."

Here, “can” means that B suggests that he buy flour in the grocery shop. For your given example, B is suggesting a location for buying flour to Jack or at least a place for Jack to consider, regarding content.
But “can” in this context also means “be able to” in this context, if the shop reopened, B has the ability to buy flour.

Thanks for replying. Can it mean suggestion here? I just feel like B is suggesting a location for buying flour to Jack or at least a place for Jack to consider.

@ChienTeLu I think it’s regarding to the content, two of these looks OK.

Thanks for confirmation. Are you a native speaker of American English?

@ChienTeLu No, I’m not a native speaker for any English. I speak Chinese in daily conversations.

Is this idiomatic?

If they reopen the grocery store around the corner, he can buy some there next week.

Yes, it is. It means:
If they reopen the grocery store around the corner, it will be possible for him to buy some there next week.

If the question is "Is it the word 'can' that makes this feel like a suggestion," the answer is no. There is a feeling of suggestion, but it's not because of the specific meaning of one word, but rather the context of the conversation.
The example is a little confusing; would Jack really want to wait a week to get flour? Is the store likely to reopen? Because of these, the sense of suggestion is a bit weakened. If we used a different context:

KID: "I want a cold drink."
ME: "You can find ice in the freezer and water at the sink."

Here it's clear that I'm suggesting to my kid that they get their own drink, just as it was implied by the context (but not by the language) that they were hoping I would do it for them.
This example uses "can" and has a strong sense of suggestion. But I could just as easily say "There's ice in the freezer and water at the sink," without using "can," and have the same implication. Or, for a different context, what if a newspaper said "A famous painting is on loan from a distant museum; people can see it at our museum until November"? It's a newspaper article, not an advertisement. It's not really prompting or suggesting, just saying "can."
It's not about that one word, it's about context.

Could is good. It can be used anywhere you say 'can', and more besides... since it can be used in past tense also. Although this flexibility means you need to must add a time reference eg I could buy it tomorrow, or I could get it in the past.
Note that I used 'can' above. Can is more definite, 'could' suggests possibilities.

“can” also suggests possibilities, right?
